# how using a F# library inside C# (and XNA) classes with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, xna

I have developed a little game using XNA 4.0 and C# (new Project->Windows Game 4.0 ).
Now I have to refactor all the game logic and write it in F#.

I created a new project for my F# library(new Project->F# Library), and added the XNA library to the project's references.

Now, how can I include the F# library inside my C# project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is referencing your F# library project from your C# one, rather than using the XNA library from in your F# project.

---

In the same way you'd reference a C# project:

Add the F# project to your solution and add a reference to the F# project in your other one

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer. I'm really new to vs.. When you say: "Add the F# project to your solution" do you mean add the dll ?

Comment: I mean `File -> Add -> Existing Project` :)

Comment: Oh..thanks..this worked! Sorry for the banal questions, but I'm using vs just from a few days..

Answer (score 1):

Compile the F# library and include it into your solution.
I had to do this a while back to get the Financial Functions library:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2008/12/04/financial-functions-for-net-released.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my own experience with writing XNA libraries in F#, but I suppose that you may need to change some project properties to be able to reference the F# library from C# XNA application. I don't know exactly which project settings need to be changed, but there are two online templates that you can download and use as a starting point:

- [F# Windows Phone Library](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/092d3f67-c938-4e53-ba1f-3baf6a15aa89)
- [F# Library for Windows Phone (XNA)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4a71154f-c590-4370-9d0f-f5072d69996f)

Aside, you can also find them if you click on "Online Templates" in the "New Project" dialog in Visual Studio and search for "F# XNA". There is quite a few, very useful, templates contributed by the F# community!